# How to load relational database tables into neo4j database

Tags: neo4j

I have tables which have millions of records. I need to load these records as nodes in neo4j.

Please help me out on how to do it as I'm new to neo4j.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy, just map your entities that should become nodes into a set of csv files and the connections that should become relationships in another set of files.

Then run them with my batch-importer: https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/tree/20#binary-download

```
import.sh nodes1.csv,nodes2.csv rels1.csv,rels2.csv
```

Add types and index information to the headers and the `batch.properties` config file as needed.

You can use the batch-importer for the initial inserter but also subsequent updates (but the database has to be shut-down for that).

It is pretty easy to connect to your existing database using its driver and then extract the information of the right shape and kind and insert it into your graph model,

Either using Cypher statements with parameters or the embedded, transactional Java API for ongoing updates. 
See: http://jexp.de/blog/2013/05/on-importing-data-in-neo4j-blog-series/

Comment: Doing this with millions of rows can be difficult. Just creating the CSVs could require quite a bit of work.  This also gets complicated if you have views that you want to import or POCO objects that are generated via stored procedures.  Extracting the data from SQL to CSV would require its own program if the table returns data larger than the memory on the system.   It would be great if there was some kind of ETL application where you could query the SQL db directly and stream that data in.

Comment: Also, just a quick thought, but the CSV import option seems like a great option for a one-time import. Which is perfect if you are switching databases, but if you are using Neo4j as a supplemental DB, you want to be able to process any updates as well.

Comment: For ETL try Pentaho, either with Neo4j JDBC driver or transactional cypher REST endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can export to CSV and import it into node (probably wont work well since you have millions of records)
You can write a program to do it (this is what I am currently working on).
This also depends on what programming languages you know... but the bottom line is, because no two databases are created equally (unless on purpose), it's very difficult to create a catch-all solution for migrating data from SQL to Neo.

The best way that I've discovered so far is to create a program that queries the tables in the database, finds all related tables (i.e. foreign keys), and imports all those table rows into Neo, labeling the nodes using the Table name, then process the foreign keys as relationships.

It's not easy.  I've been working on something for my database here for a week or so now... but I'm close!